# Check if a function is increasing or decreasing without derivative

Tags: functions

Is it possible to see if the next function is continuously increasing or decreasing without using $f'(x)$?

$f(x) = \sqrt{6x-5-x^2}$

Comment: Try using the Secant line formula for an approximation.

Comment: The function is only defined for $x \in [1,5]$.

Comment: @aleden we haven't learned that yet, so I don't think I can use it

Comment: @copper.hat right, I meant if its increasing/decreasing in the domain

Comment: For two values $a<b$ you can compare $f(a)$ with $f(b)$. If $f(a)>f(b)$, then the function must have decreased on that interval.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$f(x)^2 = 6x-5-x^2=4-(x-3)^2$.

Comment: I'm stuck at checking if it's increasing for $x_1 < x_2$. I get $|x_1-3| >= |x_2-3|$. Am I doing good? What's next?

Comment: @Pilpel There are many ways to check the monotonic behavior. One way is to observe that $f(1)^2=0$,  $f(3)^2=4$, and $f(5)^2=0$. Clearly, $f(x)$ is not monotonically increasing/decreasing.